# Date not getting displayed

Tags: javascript

I have a html page wherein i want to the date.
If I open the html file with any browser it's displaying correctly.
But when I put it in server it's not working.

My script goes like this

```
<P>Payment is due on <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
//-->
</script>.</P>
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: No error but it is not displaying the date. It only shows "Payment is due on ."

Comment: Check the console (CTRL+SHIFT+C for Chrome) and tell us if you're getting any errors. The code seems valid, so it's probably your browser blocking the script because you told it to or something. What else do you have on this page?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the semi-colons at the end of each line that matters. Also you don't need to include the "<!-- //-->" in javascript as it is now ignored (Don't expect netscape users now). It might be a problem (I guess) if the browser parse it as if it is comments so your code didn't work.

Following code is tested on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakokat/MTUMx/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one line code:

```
var today = new Date().toLocaleFormat("%m/%e/%Y");
```